# Как обратиться к функциям соседних моделей? Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Всем привет подскажите пожалуйста как правильно обращаться к функциям соседних моделей? изначально у меня все функции были в одной модели User

Сейчас из User часть функции ушло в Holiday и Party

---

Вот например функция в User в которой должны вызываться функции из Holiday и Party

```html
public function calculate($id, $startDate, $endDate)
    {
        $periodDateForm = $this->getPeriodDateForm($startDate, $endDate);
        $holidaysEmployee = $this->holiday->getHolidays($id);
        $allDateHolidaysEmployee = $this->getDateHolidayArr($holidaysEmployee);
        $allRuHolidays = $this->getApiHolidays();
        $allPartyDays = $this->delPartyDays();
        $allWekend = $this->weekend($startDate, $endDate);

        return array_diff($periodDateForm, $allDateHolidaysEmployee, $allRuHolidays, $allPartyDays, $allWekend);
    }
```

Как мне обратиться из User в модель Holiday за нужной мне функцией?

```html
$holidaysEmployee = $this->holiday->getHolidays($id);
```

---

Модель User

```html
<?php

namespace App;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class User extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'timetable_users';

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'morning_work_hours_from', 'morning_work_hours_before', 'afternoon_work_hours_from', 'afternoon_work_hours_before',
    ];

    public function holiday()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Holiday::class);
    }

    public function party()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Party::class);
    }


    public function calculate($id, $startDate, $endDate)
    {
        $periodDateForm = $this->getPeriodDateForm($startDate, $endDate);
        $holidaysEmployee = $this->holiday()->getHolidays($id);
        $allDateHolidaysEmployee = $this->getDateHolidayArr($holidaysEmployee);
        $allRuHolidays = $this->getApiHolidays();
        $allPartyDays = $this->delPartyDays();
        $allWekend = $this->weekend($startDate, $endDate);

        return array_diff($periodDateForm, $allDateHolidaysEmployee, $allRuHolidays, $allPartyDays, $allWekend);
    }

}
```

Модель Holiday

```html
<?php

namespace App;


use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class Holiday extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'timetable_holidays';

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class);
    }

    
    public function getHolidays($id)
    {
        $holidays = DB::table('timetable_holidays')
            ->where('user_id', '=', $id)
            ->get();
        return $holidays;
    }

    
    public function NameHolidaysRu()
    {
        $apiDate = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/russian__ru%40holiday.calendar.google.com/events?key=AIzaSyC8khrJO57yl4szjLOuyQrlW7R_CKgwaH0'), 1);
        $holidayDates = Arr::pluck($apiDate['items'], 'start.date');
        $nameHolidayDates = Arr::pluck($apiDate['items'], 'summary');
        $count = count($holidayDates);

        $dateAndName = array();

        for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
        {
            $dateAndName[] = [
                "date" => $holidayDates[$i],
                "name_holiday" => $nameHolidayDates[$i]
            ];
        }
        return $dateAndName;
    }

    
    public function getApiHolidays()
    {
        $apiDate = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/russian__ru%40holiday.calendar.google.com/events?key=AIzaSyC8khrJO57yl4szjLOuyQrlW7R_CKgwaH0'), 1);
        $holidayDates = Arr::pluck($apiDate['items'], 'start.date');

        $array = array_filter($holidayDates, function ($var) {
            return substr($var, 0, 4) === date("Y");
        });
        return $array;
    }

    
    public function getDateHolidayArr($holidaysEmployee)
    {
        $allHolidays = array();

        $count = count($holidaysEmployee);
        if ($count == 0)
        {
            return $allHolidays;
        }
        for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
        {
            $holidaysFrom = $holidaysEmployee[$i]->holidays_from;
            $holidaysBefore = $holidaysEmployee[$i]->holidays_before;

            $startDate = new Carbon($holidaysFrom);
            $endDate = new Carbon($holidaysBefore);

            while ($startDate->lte($endDate)) {
                $allHolidays[] = $startDate->toDateString();

                $startDate->addDay();
            }
        }
        return $allHolidays;
    }

   
    public function weekend($startDate, $endDate)
    {
        $start = strtotime($startDate);
        $end = strtotime($endDate);
        $result = array();

        while ($start <= $end)
        {
            if (date('N', $start) >= 6)
            {
                $current = date('Y-m-d', $start);
                $result[] = $current;
            } $start += 86400;
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Контроллер

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Holiday;
use App\Party;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TimetableController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $countUser = User::All()->count();
        return view('timetable', compact('countUser'));
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $rules = [
            'userId'=>'required|integer|exists:timetable_users,id',
            'startDate' => 'required|date',
            'endDate' => 'required|date|after:startDate'
        ];
        $this->validate($request, $rules);

        $id = $request['userId'];
        $startDate = $request['startDate'];
        $endDate = $request['endDate'];
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);
        $holidays = Holiday::findOrFail($id)->where("user_id", $id)->get()->sort();
        $parties = Party::all();
        $countUser = User::All()->count();
        $calculate = $user->calculate($id, $startDate, $endDate);

        return view('timetable', compact('holidays', 'user', 'countUser', 'parties', 'calculate'));

    }
}
```

Comment: Переведите, пожалуйста, на человеческий язык, что значит User hasMany Holiday? Что это вообще такое: рабочие и праздничные дни?

Comment: `$holiday = new Holiday(); $holiday->что-то`; Ну или в конструктор засунуть создание нового экземпляра.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В модели User у вас объявлена связь holiday. Это связь hasMany(один ко многим). Методы в модели принадлежат объекту. Связь hasMany возвращает коллекцию объектов.

Чтобы обратится к методу модели Holiday нужно получить объект. Например выбрать первый:

```
$user->holiday()->first()
```

у него(если он существует) можно вызвать любой публичный метод.

```
$user->holiday()->first()->getHolidays($id);
```

В вашем коде метод getHolidays избыточен. Так как делает тоже самое, что и связь

```
$user->holiday()->get()
```